# Sqlite3 Flask discord bot dashboard. TypeError: "NoneType object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, dashboard

So, i'm making a discord bot dashboard and, in the guild settings, I want to show if a category if enabled or desabled. And I maked this code:

```py
@app.route("/serveurs/<int:serveur_id>")
def serveur(serveur_id):
    if 'token' not in session:
        return redirect("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=787982190776287282&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FMEE0-1.devteaming.repl.co%2Foauth%2Fdiscord&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds")
    serveur_info = get_serveur_info(serveur_id)
    if not serveur_info:
        return redirect('/dashboard')
        
    with sqlite3.connect("dashboard.sqlite3") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM dashboardconfig WHERE guilds_id = {serveur_info['id']}")
        data = cursor.fetchone()
    print(data)
    mod = bool(data[2])
    music = bool(data[2])
    fun = bool(data[2])
    return render_template("serveur.html", serveur=serveur_info, mod=mod, music=music, fun=fun)
```

When I restart the server and I go on the endpoint it raise me this error in the terminal:

```
TypeError: "NoneType object is not subscriptable"
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in the data variable but I don't know how fix it. If anyone can help me, thanks.
PS: I make all the functions, files etc... Don't worry ;).

Comment: Which line is the error being called on?

Comment: @Still_learning Line 46 (mod variable)

Comment: Seems like there's nothing in the `data` variable, try looping through it to see if the values exist